# How to enable composite on retroarch Raspberry Pi4?

Tags: retropie, raspi-config, composite-video

I've got a pi4 working nicely over HDMI, but I prefer CRT. I've bought a 3.5mm to Scart cable, hooked it up, and I just get blank/flicker screen and audio, at the same time as HDMI. A quick look online does not help - lot's of conflicting info, and lot's of old/incorrect info.

For instance, [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=251277) doesn't work:

```
enable_tvout=1
```

The above shuts off HDMI, but still blank/flickery screen on the CRT. [Disabling overscan](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/11628/240p-and-mame-scaling) doesn't work either.

Before I blame the cable - can anyone explain exactly, in August 2021, one might output via composite successfully?

I did see an option in retro-config that forced composite, but not sure what that actually does (in terms of config.txt) as it says it removes HDMI and if the composote still doesn't work, then I'd be screwed.

Edit: Here is a link to the cable:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B075CSFQYQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o08_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I saw that pihut sell [this](https://thepihut.com/products/av-composite-cable-3-5mm-to-3-x-rca-3m) one, but was trying to avoid another link in the chain (the scart connector. My CRT just has scart inputs).

Also tried [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64009) today, also didn't work:

```
sdtv_mode=2
```

Comment: You say you have bought a cable as if there is a standard cable to go from a jack to a SCART.  Why do you think the cable you have bought should work?

Comment: Post a link to the cable. What format is your TV - PAL/NTSC ?

Comment: I thought the cable might work because the description suggested it might work, and I was trying to avoid sourcing a scart connector as well. The tv is PAL btw.